# How do I get the clients name, email and password in magento via mysql

Tags: mysql, magento

I got two queries, one that takes the email and the password and another that takes the name of the client, does anyone know or join or any query that takes this data?

```
// get client email and password

SELECT c.entity_id,c.email,
    (
    SELECT fn.value
    FROM customer_entity_varchar fn
    WHERE c.entity_id = fn.entity_id AND 
     fn.attribute_id = 12) AS password_hash, 

     (
    SELECT fn.value
    FROM customer_address_entity_varchar fn
    WHERE ca.entity_id = fn.entity_id AND 
     fn.attribute_id = 30) AS cep
    FROM customer_entity AS c
    LEFT JOIN customer_address_entity AS ca ON c.entity_id = ca.parent_id
    LEFT JOIN customer_address_entity_text AS cat ON cat.entity_id = ca.entity_id                

    GROUP BY entity_id 


// get name from client

SELECT entity_id, group_concat(VALUE SEPARATOR ' ') AS fullname FROM customer_entity_varchar AS fn INNER JOIN eav_attribute AS attr ON attr.attribute_id  = fn.attribute_id WHERE attr.attribute_code IN ( 'firstname',  'lastname' ) GROUP BY entity_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use sql, when you can use Magento's ORM. I'm assuming you want to do some sort of customer export.

Create a shell script that echos the data and save it to a file:

`php shell/customer-export.php > customers.csv`

And within your `shell/customer-export.php`, you can use customer collection (`Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')`) to achieve this.